# In VHDL 2008, can a type from a package with generics be used for a port signal?

Tags: vhdl

So I can define a package with a generic - in this case, the package takes a size as a generic and defines a vector type of that size:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package vector_package is
    generic (
        size : integer);

    subtype vector_t is std_logic_vector (size - 1 downto 0);
end package;
```

Now I can instantiate that package within an architecture to create a signal of that vector type:

```
entity foo is
end entity;

architecture rtl of foo is
    package vp_4 is new work.vector_package generic map (size => 4);
    signal vector : vp_4.vector_t;
begin
end architecture;
```

But what I want is to use the vector type for a port signal. I would have expected to be able to do something like this, but it does not appear to be valid VHDL 2008:

```
package vp_4 is new work.vector_package generic map (size => 4);

entity bar is
    port (
        signal vector : out vp_4.vector_t);
end entity;
```

This is rejected by ModelSim 10.2c with the message `(vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "vp_4".` in the line containing `signal vector : ...`.

Is there a way to use the type from the package for a port signal? I am aware of unconstrained types as an alternative, but they do not fit my requirements in the actual use case.

Comment: An expanded name - `signal vector : out work.vp_4.vector_t` or a use clause - `use work.all;` making vp4 visible in the entity declaration.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.1 Design units. A package instantiation declaration is a primary unit and doesn't share the same root declarative region with the entity declaration (12.1 Declarative region, "In addition to the preceding declarative regions, there is a *root declarative region*, not associated with a portion of the text of the description, but encompassing any given primary unit"). You've instantiated the package in the same resource library as the following entity declaration.

Comment: @user8352 Indeed, `work.vp_4.vector_t` works. Would you convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for the answer goes to [user8352](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/8352/user8352) who provided [the solution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/384380/in-vhdl-2008-can-a-type-from-a-package-with-generics-be-used-for-a-port-signal#comment936507_384380) and [some background](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/384380/in-vhdl-2008-can-a-type-from-a-package-with-generics-be-used-for-a-port-signal#comment936524_384380). The vp_4 package is found in the work library and the following will work:

```
package vp_4 is new work.vector_package generic map (size => 4);

entity bar is
    port (
        signal vector : out work.vp_4.vector_t);
end entity;
```